# Editable TableView in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

I am learning Javafx.
I want to create Editable TableView. I have tried with the model having only String fields and it works fine for me. But now my model class have Integer and Double fields. So in this case I am getting `ClassCastException`.

Please provide some source.
Thank you.

Comment: Type inconsistency between your model type and your cell editor type. Also, ask your question with a little more effort than this. Post a stacktrace maybe, give us some code maybe, ...

Comment: Thanks for your guidance in asking question as I am new over here and yes I got the solution.

Comment: If you found the solution, please take the time to post it below, and accept it.